# Is it possible to apply an agg function without listing out all the columns if I only need to apply a different function to one column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions

Given

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns=list('abcd'))
df
        a           b           c           d
    0   0.569586    0.730646    0.070111    0.226699
    1   0.092704    0.828220    0.190215    0.644188
    2   0.815397    0.281504    0.690391    0.115763
    3   0.614022    0.303781    0.738919    0.551983
```

I understand we can use `df.agg({'a':'sum','b':'mean','c':'max','d':'min'})` to apply multiple functions across multiple columns.

Is it possible to do it without listing out all the columns if I only need to apply one different  function. Something like `df.agg({'a':'sum', //df.columns[1:]// : 'mean'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, no, you need explicit column names as keys. However, you can build the dictionary like this:

```
agg_dict = {'a':'sum'}
for c in df.columns[1:]: agg_dict[c] = 'mean'

df.groupby('some_columns').agg(agg_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

pandas agg function also get list as parameter.
so you can use something like

```
params = ['sum'] + len(df.columns[1:]) * ['mean']
df.agg([params])
```